# How to get the discount value from array of slabs in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to get the discount number (value) with the predefined slabs as an array.

So for instance, if total product count is between 11 to 20 than I want to return 25 as a discount value.

It might be simple but I am not getting it how to do it. As simple foreach loop probablly won't work.

```
/**
 * The function returns the discount amount from the slabs
 *
 * @param int $products_count total number of product in cart
 *
 * @return mixed null|int returns discount value if matches else null
 */
public function product_discounts($products_count)
{

    $discount_slabs = [
        '10' => '15',
        '20' => '25',
        '30' => '35',
        '50' => '50',
    ];

    foreach ($discount_slabs as $count => $discount) {

        if ($products_count <= $count) {
            $this->discount = $discount;
        }

    }

    return $this->discount;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return the discount in your loop so that when you find the smallest slab that the product count fits in, you stop going through the subsequent values. Otherwise all values will return 50%. If you fall out of the loop, the user has more than 50 products and they will receive the last discount value, which is the largest one. Something like this:

```
public function product_discounts($products_count)
{
    $discount_slabs = [
        '10' => '15',
        '20' => '25',
        '30' => '35',
        '50' => '50',
    ];

    // set the base discount
    $this->discount = 0;

    foreach ($discount_slabs as $count => $discount) {
        if ($products_count <= $count) {
            // if less than this bracket, return the current discount
            return $this->discount;
        }
        // otherwise, increase the discount level
        $this->discount = $discount;
    }
    return $this->discount = $discount;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UHRF6)

Comment: thanks a lot for great solution. However when I set the product count to `15` it is returning `25` instead of `15`. I want if the product is between 0-10 the discount will be 15 if it is between 11 to 20 the discount will be 25 and so on...

Comment: @CodeLover but a product count of 15 is between 11 and 20 so it should be 25?

Comment: @CodeLover if you see my edit that will deal with the user having more than 50 products without changing the `discount_slabs` array.

Comment: sorry for confusion or if I am not clear. I want to apply the lowest number of discount so the slab will be `0-10 = 0, 11-20 = 15, 21-30 = 25, 31-50 = 35, 51 and above 50` This is the way I want. I am really sorry for confusion.

Comment: @CodeLover see my edit. That should do what you want.

Comment: That is an amazing solution yet simple. Thanks a lot for your quick help. I appreciate it.